# facebook comment plugin for each object in my page?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, comments

i have single php dynamic page that load image each time app user is login to my fb app
i like that each user will have its own fb comment box , how can i configure it to be unique 
for each user .
i know the php part , i have the user id , in the page but the js part of the fb comment i can't find. 
this is what i have now:

```
 <div class="block">
                <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=13xxxxxxx8434" data-width="710" data-height="60" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-block">
            <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://xxx.co" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data-href="http://xxx.co/singlePhpFile.php?userid=123"
```

just change the userid ;)

Comment: and if i like that the same user will have number of comment boxs?

Comment: also where can i find which parameter i can use in data-href

Comment: http://xxx.co/singlePhpFile.php?userid=123&commentBoxId=1
http://xxx.co/singlePhpFile.php?userid=123&commentBoxId=2
http://xxx.co/singlePhpFile.php?userid=123&commentBoxId=3

there must be the url where the box belongs to.. it is used an unique identifier